# Cant Import packages from layers in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I know this question exists several places, but even by following different guides/answers I still cant get it to work. I have no idea what I do wrong. I have a lambda Python function on AWS where i need to do a "import requests". This is my approach so far.

1. Create .zip directory of packages. Locally I do:

   pip3 install requests -t ./

   zip -r okta_layer.zip .
2. Upload .zip directory to a lambda layer:
   I go to the AWS console and go to lambda layers. I create a new layer based on this .zip file.
3. I go to my lambda python function and add the layer to the function directly form the console. I can now see the layer under "Layers" for the lambda function. Then i run the script it still complains about:

   Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'

Comment: Can you post a list of contents of directories in a tree-like format?

Comment: What libraries do you want to exacly use? Only `requests`?

Comment: I only need to use requests, this is just to figure out how i can use a lambda layer. The structure is.

Comment: The structure is ── bin
├── certifi
│   └── __pycache__
├── certifi-2020.12.5.dist-info
├── chardet
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── cli
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   └── metadata
│       └── __pycache__
├── chardet-4.0.0.dist-info
├── idna
│   └── __pycache__
├── idna-2.10.dist-info
├── requests
│   └── __pycache__
├── requests-2.25.1.dist-info
├── urllib3
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── contrib
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── _securetransport
│   │       └── __pycache__
│   ├── packages
│
│   │

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. Apparently I needed to have a .zip folder, with a "python" folder inside, and inside that "python" folder should be all the packages.

I only had all the packages in the zip folder directly without a "python" folder ...